# GAWK Script using special characters

Tags: gawk

I am having an issue using special characters. I am parsing a text file separated by tabs. I want to have the program add a  "*" to the first word in the line if a certain parameter is true.

```
if ($Var < $3)  $1 = \*$1
```

Now every time I run it I get the error that it is not the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

2 things, but without more context to test with we really can't help you much.

1. ```
   `$Var` will only have meaning if you have set it above like Var=3. Then I don't think gawk will evaluate your $3 to the value of $3. The other side of that expression `< $3` WILL expand to the value of the 3rd field. If  you're getting $Var from the shell environment, you need to let the gawk script 'see' that value, i.e.
   ```

   `awk '{ ..... if ('"$Var"' < $3) $1= "*" $1 .....}`
2. If you want the string literal '*' pre-pended, you're better off doing `$1 = "*" $1`

Without sample inputs, sample expected output, actual output and error messages, we'll be playing 20 questions here. If these comments don't solve your problem, please edit your question above to include these items.